# What is the difference between "were moved" and "were to be moved" in the if-clause of a second-conditional sentence?

Tags: conditionals

Consider the following sentence, from "*Introduction to Control Systems*" by Malgorzata Zywno:

> Note that if a summer were **to be** moved behind the block, the additional gain would be equal the value of the block gain, instead of its inverse.
>
> [bold mine]

In case it is not obvious, "*summer*" here means "*a device that sums two signals*", not the season.

But what is "*to be*" doing here? What is the difference between "*were moved*" and "*were to be moved*" in the if-clause of a second-conditional sentence?

This question is different from my previous question about that same sentence because, in the previous question, I asked why is there a "*were*" instead of "*was*" when the subject is singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two sentences is actually  *[ **were to** + be ]* rather than simply "were".

The difference in meaning is that "were to" adds a nuance of solemnity or reverence or respect.

To make it clearer that "were to" is the introduced phrase, here's an example without the passive voice:

> If my grandmother told me to quit my job, I would do it.
> If my grandmother **were to** tell me to quit my job, I would do it.

The first sentence is a simple statement of fact. The second sentence includes the same meaning as the first, and adds a slight feeling of reverence and respect for my grandmother. If I were talking about some other person I didn't particularly revere, I would never use that language.

In a context where solemnity doesn't make sense, like a technical manual, it just sounds like flowery language, which is bad style. A good editor would have removed it.